# set option of select tag using jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="align-content: center">
            <select id="start-lunch-hour" data-native-menu="false" data-overlay-theme="d" data-theme="b" name="start-time-hour" tabindex="-1" data-inline="true" data-icon="false">
                <option value="13">--</option>
                <option value="1">01</option>
                <option value="2">02</option>
                <option value="3">03</option>
                <option value="4">04</option>
                <option value="5">05</option>
                <option value="6">06</option>
                <option value="7">07</option>
                <option value="8">08</option>
                <option value="9">09</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12" selected="selected">12</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td style="align-content: center">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <select id="start-lunch-minute-digit1" data-native-menu="false" data-overlay-theme="d" data-theme="b" name="start-time-minute-digit1" tabindex="-1" data-scroll="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="false">
                    <option value="13">--</option>
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
                <select id="start-lunch-minute-digit2" data-native-menu="false" data-overlay-theme="d" data-theme="b" name="start-time-minute-digit2" tabindex="-1" data-scroll="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="false">
                    <option value="13">--</option>
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
        $("#start-time-hour").change(function () {
            var data = $(this).find(":selected").val();
            //alert(data);
            if (data == 13) {
                // This field will be output.
                if ($("#start-time-minute-digit1").find(":selected").val() != 13) {
                    $("#start-time-minute-digit1").val(13).prop('selected', true);                        
                }
                if ($("#start-time-minute-digit2").find(":selected").val() != 13) {
                    $("#start-time-minute-digit2").val(13).prop('selected', true);
                }
                //alert($("#start-time-minute-digit1").find(":selected").val());
                //alert($("#start-time-minute-digit2").find(":selected").val());
            }
            else {
                // This is normal digit input value selection for time from dropdown.
            }
        });
    });
```

Three selects are there (value attrib is same as text displayed)
start-time-hour
options 
--,0,1,2.....9
start-time-minute-digit1
options
--,0,1,...5
start-time-minute-digit2
options
--,0,1,2.....9

On changing any of them to "--" option other two must change to "--".
I wrote above function. Debuging shows values are changed but display text on page is not updated. currnetly Using jQuery mobile in .net C# mvc3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you could do this:

```
function setSelectedOption(selectID, valueToSelect){

    $("#" + selectID + " option[value='" + valueToSelect + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');    
    $("#" + selectID).selectmenu('refresh');
}

$("#start-lunch-hour").change(function () {
    var data = $(this).val();     
    if (data == 13) {
        setSelectedOption("start-lunch-minute-digit1",13);   
        setSelectedOption("start-lunch-minute-digit2",13);   
    } 
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/REthD/25/

I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, in my post I used "lunch" definitely not in code. Its a copy paste mistake in my first question. The problem still remaining - IN my page only when I refresh page text of OTHER TWO select is updated automatically not immediately when I change select option. Thanks. Let me try it.U r fiddle has only one select. please update it. I am using exactly same theme etc. just add two more select n give me sol. thanks for help

Comment: @sapatelbaps::: see my answer now and updated fiddle link is that what you are looking for???

Comment: You are rocking man - It works perfectly. Thanks a lot @maverickosama92

Answer (score 1):

Just that should be enough:

```
if (data == 13) {
    $("#start-time-minute-digit1, #start-time-minute-digit2").val(13);
}
```

And your selector is wrong for '#' should be:

```
$('#start-lunch-hour')
```

Or:

```
$('select[name=start-time-hour]')
```

Comment: @sapatelbaps Ya, just use corresponding IDs, not unrelated ones. You should try to understand code you are using...

Comment: @A.Wolff IN my page when I refresh page text is updated automatically not immediately when I change select option. BTW Thanks for u r help. What should I do?

Comment: Sorry, in my post I used "lunch" definitely not in code. Its a copy paste mistake in my first question. The problem still remaining - IN my page only when I refresh page text of other two select is updated automatically not immediately when I change select option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your id's `start-time-minute-digit1` to `start-lunch-minute-digit1`, `start-time-minute-digit2` to `start-lunch-minute-digit2` and `start-time-hour` to `start-lunch-hour`

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kveAL/192/)**</kbd>

Comment: Sorry, in my post I used "lunch" definitely not in code. Its a copy paste mistake in my first question. The problem still remaining - IN my page only when I refresh page text of other two select is updated automatically not immediately when I change select option. Thanks.